# 5D plot in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I’m using the following code to plot a 5D visualisation. Although graph is generated successfully but there is an extra item appears in the MUF40 legend (the first item). I wonder if there is something wrong in the code!

Before updating some packages (e.g. Keras , Tensoreflow, cluster and etc) on RStudio the code was working properly without any problem.

```
SLAMUF <- read.csv("/Users/Ayyoub/Desktop/MUF-SLA-Ver2.11/csla_dataset.csv")
library("ggplot2")
require("ggplot2")

SLAMUF$QoS.cat <- cut(SLAMUF$QoS, quantile(SLAMUF$QoS, (0:5)/5), include.lowest = T)

ggplot(SLAMUF, aes(x=SP.InP.SP, y=SP.SP.EU, size=MUF40, color=penalty)) +
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="black", high="red") +
  facet_grid(. ~ QoS.cat) +
  labs(subtitle = "Five ranges of QoS")+
  guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", angle=45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", angle=45),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
       )
ggsave("/Users/Ayyoub/Desktop/MUF-SLA-Ver2.11/plot3/MUF40.pdf", width=12, height=6)

> source('~/Desktop/MUF-SLA-Ver2.11/5Dvisualisation-Dataset-test.R')
Warning messages:
1: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised. 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[Produced graph with an extra item in MUF40 legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdwK.jpg)

Comment: Hi, it is hard for people to help you if they have to guess based on code only. Could you provide some insight into the structure of your data and a plot that illustrates your problem? For the data, it would be easiest if you would provide the output of `dput(head(SLAMUF))`.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for the comment! well the image is already attached in the post. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdwK.jpg

Comment: You'll need to provide the data as well.  You can post the smallest set of the data that reproduces your problem (e.g just two facets, a handful of points).  It will be some work for you to do this, but it will be much easier for others to help.  Most likely you have a blank cell in MUF40 column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing based on the labels that your `MUF40` variable is of an ordinal nature, no? (discrete categories but ordered). If that is the case, I would suggest you remove the `guides(size = guide_legend(order = 1))` statement and add the following:

```
scale_size_discrete(breaks = levels(SLAMUF$MUF40), limits = levels(SLAMUF$MUF40))
```

This should in theory restrict your size variables to just the levels in your data, if your `MUF40` variable is a factor and has the levels ordered correctly.

If this doesn't help, you may want to have a look at `SLAMUF$MUF40` values and see if there is anything out of the ordinary, such as `NA`s, `NaN`s, empty strings etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the size legend item.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, size = cyl, color = vs)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_size_continuous(guide = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
```